# Array with matrices table in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
int [] arr = {-1,1,1,1,1}
int [] num = {23,24,25,26}
```

If I just want to `sum {24,25,26}`, how to call from `arr[1,1,1,1}`? For example: num 23 in index 0 of `arr`, num 24 in index 1 of `arr` and so on.

```
for (//..........) {
    System.out.print (//.....)
}
```

Please note: array in `arr` is a table only. It does not mean summing, like a matrices table.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you want to find the sum of a subset of a 1D matrix?

Comment: yes, to see in array table in arr[]... array numb 24 are in index []arr (1), num 25 are in index []arr (2)...

Comment: First of all 23 has the index 0, and why don't you use directly int[i] to get your array elements?

Comment: can you help me.. i can send to image in your profil... so i confused to explain...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have come up with, you will need a method.

```
public int sum(int[] matrix, int ... args)
{
int sum = 0;
for(int index : args)
{
sum += matrix[index];
}
return sum;
}
```

This would basically take the matrix, then based upon any number of other arguments you gave, take the indexes and sum the values.

Answer (score 0):

This will add the second array to the first, and ignore any items that are on indexes larger than the first array (for instance, if first array is {3, 4} and the second is {5, 3, 4} the 4 in the second array will be ignored).

```
private void sumArrays(int[] first, int[] second){
    for(int i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
        if(i >= second.length){
            break;
        }

        first[i] += second[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the sum of your num array elements beginning from a parameter index then try this:

```
int [] num = {23,24,25,26};
public int CalculateSum(int index)
{
    int sum =0;
  if(index<num.length)
  {
    for(int i=index;i<num.length;i++) {
        sum+=num[i];
    }
  }
return sum;
}
```